# numpy first occurence in array for an array of reference values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

Given a threshold `alpha` and a numpy array `a`, there are multiple possibilities for finding the first index `i` such that `arr[i] > alpha`; see [Numpy first occurrence of value greater than existing value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16243955/353337):

```
numpy.searchsorted(a, alpha)+1
numpy.argmax(a > alpha)
```

In my case, `alpha` can be either a scalar or an array of arbitrary shape. I'd like to have a function `get_lowest` that works in both cases:

```
alpha = 1.12
arr = numpy.array([0.0, 1.1, 1.2, 3.0])
get_lowest(arr, alpha)  # 2

alpha = numpy.array(1.12, -0.5, 2.7])
arr = numpy.array([0.0, 1.1, 1.2, 3.0])
get_lowest(arr, alpha)  # [2, 0, 3]
```

Any hints?

Comment: Just to clarify: `arr` is always 1d and sorted?   And you treat the elements of `alpha` independently?  What's the relative size of `arr` and `alpha`?  A simple iteration on `alpha` might be the fastest, especially if `searchsorted` is the optimal tool for a single value.

Comment: @hpaulj `alpha` can be an array of arbitrary shape, and is typically much larger than `arr`.

Comment: I'm reminded of a `padding` problem - with variable length lists.  @Divakar's style of solution might be useful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43924187/load-data-with-rows-of-different-sizes-into-numpy-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) actually does the trick:

```py
np.searchsorted(a, alpha)
```

The `axis` argument to `argmax` helps out; this

```py
np.argmax(numpy.add.outer(alpha, -a) < 0, axis=-1)
```

does the trick. Indeed

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0.0, 1.1, 1.2, 3.0])

alpha = 1.12
    
np.argmax(np.add.outer(alpha, -a) < 0, axis=-1)  # 0
np.searchsorted(a, alpha)  # 0

alpha = np.array([1.12, -0.5, 2.7])
np.argmax(np.add.outer(alpha, -a) < 0, axis=-1)  # [2 0 3]
np.searchsorted(a, alpha)  # [2 0 3]
```

Comment: searchsorted didn't work for me - but the argmax / outer route did. Probably because not sorted :\

Answer (score 2):

You can use broadcasting:

```
In [9]: arr = array([ 0. ,  1.1,  1.2,  3. ])
In [10]: alpha = array([ 1.12, -0.5 ,  2.7 ])
In [11]: np.argmax(arr > np.atleast_2d(alpha).T, axis=1)
Out[11]: array([2, 0, 3])
```

To collapse multidimensional arrays, you can use `np.squeeze`, but you might have to do something special if you want a Python float in your first case:

```
def get_lowest(arr, alpha):
    b = np.argmax(arr > np.atleast_2d(alpha).T, axis=1)
    b = np.squeeze(b)
    if np.size(b) == 1:
        return float(b)
    return b
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, this returns an array (of shape `1,1`) if the input is a float. I need a float.

Comment: Easily fixed @NicoSchlömer, no?