# Assign values to numpy array using row indices

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting, numpy-slicing

Suppose I have two arrays, `a=np.array([0,0,1,1,1,2]), b=np.array([1,2,4,2,6,5])`. Elements in `a` mean the row indices of where `b` should be assigned. And if there are multiple elements in the same row, the values should be assigned in order.
So the result is a 2D array `c`:

```
c = np.zeros((3, 4))
counts = {k:0 for k in range(3)}
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    c[a[i], counts[a[i]]]=b[i]
    counts[a[i]]+=1
print(c)
```

Is there a way to use some fancy indexing method in numpy to get such results faster (without a for loop) in case these arrays are big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to run your code to actually see what it produced.  There are limits to what I can 'run' in my head.

```
In [230]: c                                                                                            
Out[230]: 
array([[1., 2., 0., 0.],
       [4., 2., 6., 0.],
       [5., 0., 0., 0.]])
In [231]: counts                                                                                       
Out[231]: {0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 1}
```

Omitting this information may be delaying possible answers.  'vectorization' requires thinking in whole-array terms, which is easiest if I can visualize the result, and look for a pattern.

## This looks like a `padding` problem.

```
In [260]: u, c = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)                                                      
In [261]: u                                                                                            
Out[261]: array([0, 1, 2])
In [262]: c                                                                                            
Out[262]: array([2, 3, 1])      # cf with counts
```

[Load data with rows of different sizes into Numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43924187/load-data-with-rows-of-different-sizes-into-numpy-array/43925032#43925032)

Working from previous padding questions, I can construct a mask:

```
In [263]: mask = np.arange(4)<c[:,None]                                                                
In [264]: mask                                                                                         
Out[264]: 
array([[ True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False, False]])
```

and use that to assign the `b` values to `c`:

```
In [265]: c = np.zeros((3,4),int)                                                                      
In [266]: c[mask] = b                                                                                  
In [267]: c                                                                                            
Out[267]: 
array([[1, 2, 0, 0],
       [4, 2, 6, 0],
       [5, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Since `a` is already sorted we might get the counts faster than with `unique`. Also it will have problems if `a` doesn't have any values for some row(s).

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, this is a padding problem. If a doesn't have any values for some row, one way to get around is to use  ```d=np.zeros(3), d[u]=c,mask = np.arange(4)<d[:,None]  ```